# Hough Circular Transform

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

Im trying to implement Hough Transform using gradient direction. I know that there is an implementation in OpenCv but I want to do it myself.

I'm using Sobel to get the X and Y gradient. Then for every pixel the

- magnitute ---> `sqrt(sobelX^2 + sobelY^2)`
- directions --> `atan2(sobelY,sobelX) * 180/PI`

if the magnitude is higher then 220 (so almost black) this is the edge.
And then the direction is used on the circle equation.

But the results are not acceptable. Any help?

I know there are the `cv::polar` and `cv::cartToPolar`, but I want to optimize code so that all equations will be calculated on fly, no empty loops.

[image: Result of HoughTransform]

```
cv::Mat sobelX,sobelY;
        Sobel(mat, sobelX, CV_32F, 1, 0, kernelSize, 1, 0, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
        Sobel(mat, sobelY, CV_32F, 0, 1, kernelSize, 1, 0, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
        //cv::Canny(mat,mat,100,200,kernelSize,false);
        debug::showImage("sobelX",sobelX);
        debug::showImage("SobelY",sobelY);
        debug::showImage("MAT",mat);
        cv::Mat magnitudeMap,angleMap;
    magnitudeMap = cv::Mat::zeros(mat.rows,mat.cols,mat.type());
    angleMap = cv::Mat::zeros(mat.rows,mat.cols,mat.type());
        std::vector<cv::Mat> hough_spaces(max);
        for(int i=0; i<max; ++i)
        {
            hough_spaces[i] = cv::Mat::zeros(mat.rows,mat.cols,mat.type());
        }
        for(int x=0; x<mat.rows; ++x)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<mat.cols; ++y)
            {

                const float magnitude = sqrt(sobelX.at<uchar>(x,y)*sobelX.at<uchar>(x,y)+sobelY.at<uchar>(x,y)*sobelY.at<uchar>(x,y));
                const float theta= atan2(sobelY.at<uchar>(x,y),sobelX.at<uchar>(x,y)) * 180/CV_PI;
                magnitudeMap.at<uchar>(x,y) = magnitude;
                if(magnitude > 225)//mat.at<const uchar>(x,y) == 255)
                {
                    for(int radius=min; radius<max; ++radius)
                    {

                        const int a = x - radius * cos(theta);//lookup::cosArray[static_cast<int>(theta)];//+ 0.5f;
                        const int b = y - radius * sin(theta);//lookup::sinArray[static_cast<int>(theta)]; //+ 0.5f;
                        if(a >= 0 && a <hough_spaces[radius].rows && b >= 0 && b<hough_spaces[radius].cols)                             {
                            hough_spaces[radius].at<uchar>(a,b)+=10;
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        debug::showImage("magnitude",magnitudeMap);
        for(int radius=min; radius<max; ++radius)
        {
            double min_f,max_f;
            cv::Point min_loc,max_loc;
            cv::minMaxLoc(hough_spaces[radius],&min_f,&max_f,&min_loc,&max_loc);
            if(max_f>=treshold)
            {
                circles.emplace_back(cv::Point3f(max_loc.x,max_loc.y,radius));
                // debug::showImage(std::to_string(radius).c_str(),hough_spaces[radius]);

            }
        }
        circles.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: _but I wan't to optimize code that all equations will be calculated on fly, no empty loops_. I don't think you will increase performance by implementing already optimized functions yourself.

Comment: Yes i know, but I wan't to understand how it works not using all the library functions. But when I'm using the cartToPolar there is no change. The result are still non acceptable.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but have you tried looking at the output of your  sobelX, sobelY and magnitude image? Does it give the result you expect?